# How to change message content of PushNotification?

Tags: android, cordova, push-notification, sencha-touch, google-cloud-messaging

I am getting notification on my android device. My message content of cotification is showing: 
**<missing message content>**
I am using PushPlugin (https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin) project to build my code.
Part of my NotificationController.js code is:

```
registerDevice: function() {    
    var pushNotification = window.plugins.pushNotification;

    if (device.platform == 'android' || device.platform == 'Android') {
        pushNotification.register(AppDemo.app.getControllerInstances()['AppDemo.controller.NotificationController'].recieveGCMRegistrationId, 
                AppDemo.app.getControllerInstances()['AppDemo.controller.NotificationController'].errorHandler,
                {"senderID":"624986650855","ecb":"AppDemo.app.getControllerInstances()['AppDemo.controller.NotificationController'].onNotificationGCM"});
    }
},
recieveGCMRegistrationId: function(result) {
    AppDemo.app.getControllerInstances()['AppDemo.controller.NotificationController'].handleRegistrationId(result, 'GCM');
},
onNotificationGCM: function(event) 
{

    switch( event.event ) {
        case 'registered':
        alert("regd id"+event.regid);
            this.handleRegistrationId(event.regid, 'GCM');
            break;

        case 'message':
            alert('Notification Received');
            break;

        case 'error':
            alert('Error received from GCM Server : ' + error);
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
},
handleRegistrationId: function (registrationId, deviceType) 
{
    window.localStorage.setItem("registrationId", registrationId);
}
```

My Server is sending JSON string alongwith GCM notification in the format:

```
{"taskName”:" test task name","taskType":" Adhoc Task","taskDescription":"test task description"}
```

Code inside GCMIntentService.java inside my Android build project is:

```
public void createNotification(Context context, Bundle extras)
{
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    String appName = getAppName(this);

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, PushHandlerActivity.class);
    notificationIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    notificationIntent.putExtra("pushBundle", extras);

    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);        

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = 
        new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setSmallIcon(context.getApplicationInfo().icon)
            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
            .setContentTitle(appName)
            .setTicker(appName)
            .setContentIntent(contentIntent);

    String message = extras.getString("message");
    if (message != null) {
        mBuilder.setContentText(message);
    } else {
        mBuilder.setContentText("<missing message content>");
    }

    String msgcnt = extras.getString("msgcnt");
    if (msgcnt != null) {
        mBuilder.setNumber(Integer.parseInt(msgcnt));
    }

    mNotificationManager.notify((String) appName, NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
    tryPlayRingtone();
}
```

How could I be able to change the message content of my notification from **<missing message content>** to the JSON string format send to me from server alongwith the gcm notification?
I want that of the type:
**<taskName, taskType, taskDescription>**
Please help me in this context.
Any help would be really appreciated...
:)

Comment: Where is the code you are using to send the message from your server?

Comment: actually, i am in client-side development team. My server-side team told me that they are sending a json string of the above given format, and I have to show that in message content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't use Phonegap myself, but I can only assume that these JSON elements go into the GCM as extras just like 'message'.

Therefore in your Java code have:

```
String taskName = extras.getString("taskName");
String taskType = extras.getString("taskType");
String taskDescription = extras.getString("taskDescription");
```

Do a null check on them and then concatenate/format these Strings into the 'message' that you send to the mBuilder.

```
mBuilder.setContentText(message);
```

.